# linux using watch command with a seperator

Tags: linux, terminal, watch, tail

I have 3 files and I want watch the changes of these files with 'watch' command. But these 3 files have a lot of row and I just want see the last 3 rows with 'tail'. There is no problem at here. I can use this command for this:

```
watch 'tail -3 file1; tail-3 file2; tail -3 file3'
```

This command give me an output like this:

```
Every 2.0s: tail -3 file1; tail -3 file2; tail -3 file3
file1 row9
file1 row10
file1 row11
file2 row9
file2 row10
file2 row11
file3 row9
file3 row10
file3 row11
```

I want to seperate these rows with any seperator and see the result as like this:

```
Every 2.0s: tail -3 file1; tail -3 file2; tail -3 file3
file1 row9
file1 row10
file1 row11
-----
file2 row9
file2 row10
file2 row11
-----
file3 row9
file3 row10
file3 row11
```

The seperator doesn't matter. I just want to see the results as seperated.

Comment: Are you unhappy with the headers shown by `tail -n3 file1 file2 file3`?  You could always filter with Sed or Awk to massage to how you want.  But it's not really a programming question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would put the files in a loop like this:

```
watch 'for file in {file1,file2,file3}; do tail -v -n3 $file; echo '----'; done'
```

Output:

```
==> file1 <==
row9
row10
row11
-----
==> file2 <==
row9
row10
row11
-----
==> file3 <==
row9
row10
row11
-----
```